# Java.io.DataInputStream.readFloat() in Golang

Tags: java, go

I am writing a program that emulates the functionality of the following Java program:

```java
public class MFCC {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, Exception {
    System.out.println("MFCC Coefficient Extractor");
    // Executables
    String sox = "/usr/bin/sox";
    String x2x = "/usr/local/bin/x2x";
    String frame = "/usr/local/bin/frame";
    String window = "/usr/local/bin/window";
    String mcep = "/usr/local/bin/mcep";
    String swab = "/usr/local/bin/swab";

    // Command Line Options
    String WavFile = "/output/audio.wav";
    String RawFile = WavFile + ".raw";
    String frameLength = "400";
    String frameLengthOutput = "512";
    String framePeriod = "80";
    String mgcOrder = "24";
    String mfccFile = WavFile + ".mfc";

    String soxcmd = sox + " " + WavFile + " " + RawFile;
    launchProc(soxcmd, "sox", WavFile);

    // MFCC
    String mfcccmd = x2x + " +sf " + WavFile + " | " + frame + " -l " + frameLength + " -p " + framePeriod + " | " + window
        + " -l " + frameLength + " -L " + frameLengthOutput + " -w 1 -n 1 | " + mcep + " -a 0.42 -m " + mgcOrder
        + " -l " + frameLengthOutput + " | " + swab + " +f > " + mfccFile;

    launchBatchProc(mfcccmd, "getSptkMfcc", WavFile);

        int numFrames;
    DataInputStream mfcData = null;
        Vector<Float> mfc = new Vector<Float>();

        mfcData = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(mfccFile)));
        try {
            while (true) {
                mfc.add(mfcData.readFloat());
            }
        } catch (EOFException e) {
        }
        mfcData.close();

    System.out.println("Coefficient vector length: " + mfc.size());
    System.out.println("The coefficients are: " + mfc);
  }
}
```

(Run it by cloning [this repo](https://github.com/gilgameshskytrooper/javamfcc.git) and running `docker build -t javamfcc:latest . && docker run --name javamfcc --rm -v $PWD/output:/output javamfcc:latest`)

The basic gist of what this program is by running an audio file through a list of pipes of executables provided by [the SPTK project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sp-tk/), and parsing the final output by reading 4 bytes as a float, and appending those values to a single vector.

I more or less have a good idea of how to get the pipes, but am having trouble figuring out how I can loop through the final *io.Reader and read every 4 bytes as a float (as is accomplished in `Java.io.DataInputStream.readFloat()`) done with the following code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fileName := "/output/audio.wav"
    frameLength := 400
    frameLengthOutput := 512
    framePeriod := 80
    mgcOrder := 24

    mfcc := exec.Command("mfcc.sh", "/output/"+fileheader.Filename, strconv.Itoa(frameLength), strconv.Itoa(frameLengthOutput), strconv.Itoa(framePeriod), strconv.Itoa(mgcOrder))
    mfccout, mfccerr := mfcc.Output()
    if mfccerr != nil {
        log.Println("Error executing mfcc.sh")
        panic(mfccerr)
    }

    b := bytes.NewReader(mfcc)

}
```

mfcc.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
frameLength=$2
frameLengthOutput=$3
framePeriod=$4
mgcOrder=$5

echo "filename: "$filename
echo "frameLength: "$frameLength
echo "frameLengthOutput: "$frameLengthOutput
echo "framePeriod: "$framePeriod
echo "mgcOrder: "$mgcOrder
x2x +sf $filename | frame -l $frameLength -p $framePeriod | window -l $frameLength -L $frameLengthOutput -w 1 -n 1 | mcep -a 0.42 -m $mgcOrder -l $frameLengthOutput | swab +f
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read first example shows reading a float.

Comment: I'm not trying to read a single float, I need to read a byte slice. Why did you downvote my question?

Comment: @GilgameshSkytrooper: If you don't want to read a float, and want to read a byte slice, I'm afraid I don't understand what you want. Your description says you want to read 4 byte chunks into float values, in which case you can use the `binary` package as shown in the example, or read them into a uint32 and convert that directly to a float32 in the exact same manner as described in the java `DataInput` documentation.

Comment: Sorry, the data type I am trying to read is float slice. The code I am translating from Java declares a float Vector, then  loops through a DataInputStream, and running `readFloat()`, and pushing those values to the vector. I'm not entirely sure, if this helps you understand, but here's what I have: https://gist.github.com/gilgameshskytrooper/80dc43d97475024ac2c9c9bfa1f3a37e (changed since last time because the pure Go piping stuff didn't work out)

Comment: The code I am translating is lines 591-610 of the file at https://github.com/marytts/marytts/blob/4aada82d17abf01a7ea0d8bce755866ebaa6e235/marytts-runtime/src/main/java/marytts/htsengine/HTSEngineTest.java

Comment: @GilgameshSkytrooper: please include the relevant code in the question, and it would be helpful to distill this down to a [mcve]. You seem to have multiple issues here causing confusion.

Comment: touche. I will reformulate my original question. Thanks

Comment: To start you off in the right direction, you're reading into a 0-length slice, which is going to yield 0 values. You only want to read 4-byte values, but you're using float64. Are you sure you want `LitttleEndian`? I'm fairly certain the java is going to interpret the values as `BigEndian`.

Comment: I read that in general, OS level IO is all LittleEndian while network transferred bytes are BigEndian. But good to know.